# Start Python executable on Windows start-up

Tags: python

I have been researching for long, trying to find how to make a .exe made with python execute itself each time that Windows starts, without having to create  a setup wizard, or having to manually store the program in the Start Menu folder but I have not found anything.
What I want is that, by simply executing the exe once, it auto executes on each windows start-up.
It has occured to me to get the program to create a shortcut to itself, and auto store it in the start menu folder.
Is that possible?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a `task scheduler`?

Comment: @drec4s Not exactly. What I want is that, by simply clicking the exe, it auto executes on each startup and I want to somehow implement that in the python code, so that it is much easier and faster for people who use my program

Comment: You have to access the windows registry and create a Run key for the current user. That's a duplicate from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605055/creating-new-value-inside-registry-run-key-with-python

Comment: @progmatico But can I do that from the python program?

Comment: Yes, make your program create a registry key like in the answer from the link, but set the key value point to your program executable path and name. When the program is executed the first time it creates the key, and then it will run on windows user logon. Now it has to be or copy itself to a previous known place, matching the pathname in the key. Making an executable from the python script is a different thing and has nothing to do with the autorun question, but you can search SO and find answers for that too. There are many tools to do that.

Comment: @progmatico Thank you very much, I did not intend to duplicate the question, but, as I did not know about the registry run keys, I could not search that. Sorry